# Add Coins per second in an Python clicker game

Tags: python

im very new in python. Im trying to build a idle clicker game. If you click you get a coins. You should be abled to buy "Autoclickers" that means you get automatically coins per second.
I curenntly have my code in a while loop that ends when i write "EXIT". And i have no idea how i can implement time and add the auto coins while other stuff happends.
All in all: Want to implement Coins per second

my code:

```
print("Welcome to the game")

coins = 1
a = 0
shop = 0
coinsperclick = 1
nothing = 999
coinspersec = 1


def help():
    print("'help' für Hilfe", '\n', "Enter für coins", '\n', "'shop' für den Shop")


help()


a = input()
while a != "EXIT":
    a = input()
    if a == "shop":
        print("Number 0:     EXIT Shop      Cost: 0")
        print("Number 1:     Clicker +1     Cost: 50")
        print("Number 2:     CPS +1         Cost: 100")
        shop = eval(input("What do you want to buy?"))
        if shop == 0:
            nothing = nothing
        if shop == 1:
            kaufmenge = eval(input("How many do you want to buy?"))
            coinsperclick = coinsperclick+kaufmenge
            coins = coins-(kaufmenge*50)
        if shop == 2:
            kaufmenge = eval(input("How many do you want do buy?"))
            coinspersec = coinspersec+kaufmenge
            coins = coins-(kaufmenge*100)
    if a == "help":
        help()
    if a == "":
        coins = coins+coinsperclick
        print(coins)
        a = 1
```

Comment: Btw. I know the code is very bad. Im coding python since a day now.

Comment: You'll probably need to use threading, since you need to wait for user input & also increment a timer/coins simultaneously.

Comment: Threading seems to me to be overkill in this case and rather  difficult for a first day programmer :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use 2 properties: 1 for the coin counter and 1 for the coins per second. Any time you use the coin property you calculate the new coins you've earned since the last time you've used the coin counter, which kinda "pretends" like the coins have been counting up all along, but rather just "materializes" the coins whenever they matter.

```py
import time

class Game:
  def __init__(self):
    self._coins = 0
    self._last_time = time.time()
    self._cps = 1
  
  @property
  def coins(self):
    self._collect_coins()
    return self._coins

  def _collect_coins(self):
    new_time = time.time()
    self._coins += self._cps * (new_time - self._last_time)
    self._last_time = new_time

  @property
  def coins_per_second(self):
    return self._cps

  @coins_per_second.setter
  def coins_per_second(self, value):
    self._collect_coins()
    self._cps = value
```

This code calculates your new coin value whenever you use it:

```py
>>> g = Game()
>>> g.coins
0
>>> time.sleep(2)
>>> g.coins
2
```

And it makes sure that whenever the Game's `coins_per_second` changes you collect however many coins you earned before changing the coins per second that you'll start earning at the new rate from there on out:

```py
>>> g = Game()
>>> time.sleep(1)
>>> g.coins_per_second = 2
>>> time.sleep(1)
>>> g.coins
3
```

If you didn't collect the coins when the coins per second changed you'd incorrectly count both these seconds at the changed rate of 2 coins per second.

Answer (score 1):

```
import time

coins = 0
while True:
     coins += 1
     time.sleep(1)
```

Adding one every second